# Error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I am trying to fetch the data from Firestore by Stream. But it is giving me error. I am trying to fetch a String and a List but I don't know what to change in code to fetch the List. In code, `'name'` field is String and `'overview'` field is a List.

```
import 'package:firebaseAuth/firebaseAuthDemo.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class FindDiseases extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  const FindDiseases({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FindDiseasesState createState() => _FindDiseasesState();
}

class _FindDiseasesState extends State<FindDiseases> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  List diseasesList = [];
  dynamic data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          "Diseases List",
        ),
      ),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("diseases")
              .orderBy('id')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(user['name']),
                      subtitle: Text(user['overview']),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Data is something like as shown below:

```
"name": "Agoraphobia",
"overview": "[
'Losing weight.', 'Stopping medications or supplements.', 'Having surgery.'
]"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using

```
subtitle: Text(user['overview']),
```

as a string while in data this data is in list format try to get index wise data from it then try to show as string

Answer (score 0):

In your data "overview" is a type of list and you are trying to get it as string.

```
List<String> list = user['overview'];

String data = String.join(", ", list); 

 return Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(user['name']),
                  subtitle: Text(data),
                ),
              ),
            );
```